# Row name of the highest number in Excel

Tags: excel

I was wondering how can I get the row name of the highest number in Excel?

[image]

Is there any way for the name `James Smith` to be presented in a cell calculating who has the highest point score instead of the actual number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(C:C),C:C,0)) & " " & INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(C:C),C:C,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `INDEX/MATCH` where you get the row number in the table from the `MATCH` function:

[image]

I used a Table and structured references for the benefits of automatic naming, sizing of the named ranges, and independence from absolute cell locations.

Comment: not that familiar with the benefits of tables so I am glad to see this and learn from it.

Comment: @Forwarded I particularly like the auto-expansion for both rows and columns (with formulas and formats) along with the dynamic names.